Fresh install of 24.04, RAM keeps climbing until the system locks
Even with only a few apps open, my memory just won't ever stop increasing. I have 32 GB installed. I found a command that increased my swap to 40 GB. That helped a lot, but eventually even it goes to 100% and I either freeze up or it closes everything & goes to the lock screen. The worst process is Gnome-Shell. It can often get near 40 GB.
I've been using Ubuntu since 16.04. I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and never had this problem before. I haven't added any programs except from the App Center. My CPU usage has not been a problem. The highest it gets is 50-60%. Been researching for days. Found a number of people with the same problem, but no good answers. Right now my only hope is this is some bug that will eventually get fixed by an update. I've gone up a gig just since I started this post.



Did you try to disable all GNOME add-ons?

I'm still a bit of a newbie. Don't know how to do that. I've learned to be cautious & clone regularly because one wrong command line can trash you. Found a program to show all installed extensions & let you switch them on or off, but not supported on 24.04

Press the windows key (⊞) and then start typing Extension. Run that program. Toward the top of the displayed window, you should see a toggle switch that will let you disable (or re-enable) all extensions. Try to use your system with all extensions disabled. The command gnome-extensions list will list all extensions; it may be a good idea to [edit] your question and add the list displayed into your original question above.

They are all turned off already except two I want. The desktop clock widget & the dock.
